# Dynamically create select Tag JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
      $.each(result, function() {
                                $.each(this, function(k, item) {
                                    var s = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");

                         html += '<tr>'; 
                         html += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';    
                         html += '<td>' + item.admno + '</td>';
                         html += '<td>' + item.stud_name + '</td>'; 
                         html += '<td>' + item.remark + '</td>';          
                         html+= '<td>'+s+'</td>';
             for(var val in item) 
        {
         $("<option />", {value: val.id, text: item[val.stud_name]}).appendTo(s);
            }
 html += '</tr>'; 
 });
            });
           $('.tbody').html(html);
```

I have to append select tag after remark I tried to append using $(s).wrap.  Help me to append select dynamically using jquery

Comment: what is in the result??

Comment: [object][object]@Sushil

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your problem and provide the link??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var result = [];
var obj = {};
obj.id = 1;
obj.admno = '123';
obj.stud_name = 'Ali';
obj.remark = 78;
result.push(obj);

var obj2 = {};
obj2.id = 1;
obj2.admno = '235';
obj2.stud_name = 'Ahmad';
obj2.remark = 78;
result.push(obj2);

$.each(result, function( index, item ) {

  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>'; 
  html += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';    
  html += '<td>' + item.admno + '</td>';
  html += '<td>' + item.stud_name + '</td>'; 
  html += '<td>' + item.remark + '</td>';   



  var select = "<select id='selectId' name='selectName' >";

  $.each(result,  function(i,val)
        {
          select += 
            "<option  value = '" + val.id + "'>" + val.stud_name + " </option>";

             }
         );
    select += "</select>";

    html += '<td>'+select+'</td>';

    html += '</tr>'; 

  $('.tbody').append(html);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.each(result, function() {
                         $.each(this, function(k, item) {


                         html += '<tr>'; 
                         html += '<td>' + item.id + '</td>';    
                         html += '<td>' + item.admno + '</td>';
                         html += '<td>' + item.stud_name + '</td>'; 
                         html += '<td>' + item.remark + '</td>';          
                         html+= '<td>';
                         html += "<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" >";

                       for(var val in item) 
                        {
                          html+="<option value="+val.id+">item[val.stud_name]</option>", 

                        }

                        html+= '</select>';
                        html+= '</td>';
                        html += '</tr>'; 
                       });
                     });

                $('.tbody').html(html);
```